# Upgrade backend functionality of website - opinions wanted on different options

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net, asp-classic

We have a website that originated in 2001, which started with some simple classic ASP scripts that enabled website viewers to dynamically configure products by following a step by step process of choosing product accessories, etc, using Access as the data source.  The website expanded eventually to currently keep track of a simple, small encrypted member list with usernames and passwords to enable access to restricted areas of the website.

In the future, we're planning an expansion of the website and the backend will need an overhaul obviously to a more modern, scalable framework. The first inclination is to convert the classic ASP VBscript to VB.net.  Another option would be to convert the backend functionality using PHP and MySQL.

Which would be easiest to convert to, simplest to maintain and scalable for a future expansion of functionalities?

Comment: This question isn't really appropriate to SO, because there there is no specific answer, but it can also provoke disagreements over what are the best technologies to use

Comment: I understand your comment - that totally makes sense, but the two basic answers below are helpful and pretty much what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lots of answers. If you already have developers, then a heavy influence would be what they are comfortable with.

If you don't already have a team, then there's lots of factors to consider. You need to learn the different languages, frameworks, platforms, & databases.

**Languages**. This is the set of core commands that the computer recognizes. Big ones are:

- VBScript
- VB.NET
- C#
- PHP
- RUBY

**Frameworks**. Frameworks are large libraries that do a lot of the work for you. The core of the framework will still be one of the above languages, but there are also commands that call library routines. Big ones are:

- ASP.NET & ASP.NET MVC (runs VB.NET, C#.NET, & other samller languages)
- CAKE (runs PHP)
- Ruby on Rails (runs Ruby)

**Platforms**. This is the type of server running your website. The two big ones are:

- Windows (can run almost anything)
- Apache (can not run MS products like ASP.NET)

**Databases**. Several good options here. Big ones are:

- MS SQL Server (requires license to be purchased, and also requires
  Windows)
- MySQL (Free license)
- MS Access (wouldn't recommend for anything but the smallest of
  projects)

***There are many, many more that could be listed. I tried to hit all the big ones.***

Now, with all that being said, Ruby on Rails (RoR) is the most used for new development right now (according to Google trends). Lots of online libraries & help can be found.
PHP is huge, but is declining.
If you use ASP.NET, I would recommend using MS SQL Server as the a lot of the wizards fail when using MySQL.
If you use PHP, CAKE, or RoR, then MySQL would probably be more compatible with existing libraries.

**Good luck with your upgrade.**

Comment: Where's your evidence that PHP is declining? Google don't seem to think so, having just announced running PHP in Google App Engine; nor does w3tech

Comment: http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=php,+ruby&cmpt=q&geo=US

Comment: Search interest !== usage interest, and usa !== worldwide

Answer (score 2):

It is a matter of preference and what the team is comfortable with. If you are better aligned towards ASP then stick to that and vice virsa. There is no 'right' answer or 'right' language for the job. They both do practically the same thing albeit in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO PHP is equivalent to Classic ASP for many reasons, including that it is a scripting language. If you are going to move away from Classic ASP, rather than move horizontally, I would *progress* by choosing .Net or Ruby.

Comment: +1 for a good answer. But hey, instead of moving horizontally or progressing, why don't we step backwards and do the whole thing in COBOL? lol

Answer (score -3):

PHP is the easiest language for writing websites and it does not lack any needed features. Development is faster and cheaper with PHP. There are more PHP coders than .NET on account of the easy learning curve. Other languages may be "faster", but unless you have a very very large scale application this speed difference is irrelevant.

You will probably be making your site from the ground up and the difference in effort to "convert" your code won't matter.

Comment: I completely disagree, and that's why the question doesn't belong here :-)